# Simplifying bitwise expressions

Tags: boolean-algebra

Using various methods it is possible to simply boolean expressions consisting of boolean operators and binary variables.

In programming languages another closely related set of operators exists: bitwise operators ([on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)).  These operators take a sequence of binary variables $a=(a_1, ... a_n)$ and operate on the sequence as a whole.

E.g.: $a$ AND $b = (a_1\land b_1, ..., a_n \land b_n)$

Common operators are bitwise NOT, AND, OR, XOR and various left and right bit-shifts.

Do there exist methods to simplify arbitrary bitwise expressions? (Or alternatively certain classes of bitwise expressions?)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus ?